# Can you addTarget to UIButton in NSObject class?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you addTarget to a UIButton in an NSObject class? Or will that class not work?

```
class Support: NSObject {

    func helpButton(viewController: ProfileVC) {

    let helpButton = viewController.helpButton
    helpButton.frame.size = CGSizeMake(35.0, 35.0)
    helpButton.layer.cornerRadius = helpButton.frame.height/2
    helpButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    helpButton.layer.borderColor = lightColoredFont.CGColor
    helpButton.setTitle("?", forState: .Normal)
    helpButton.setTitleColor(lightColoredFont, forState: .Normal)
    helpButton.titleLabel?.font = fontSmaller
    helpButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showOptions"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    helpButton.center.y = viewController.logoutButton.center.y
    helpButton.frame.origin.x = (viewController.view.bounds.width - viewController.logoutButton.frame.maxX)
    viewController.view.addSubview(helpButton)

    }

    func showOptions() {

        print("showing")

    }

}
```

The print is not showing. Even if I feed an instantiated support class into the target for the button it will not work. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: some update about? I lost many time looking for something wrong in my code. :(

Comment: Dokun provided an answer that works.

Comment: @PhilAndrews, Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

`NSObject` does not inherit from anything in UIKit. Your inheritance should be the other way around. Perhaps you could make a `UIButton` that has a property of type `NSObject` to carry some accompanying information?

Comment: It's odd that it can be done with a tap recognizer as long as you assign the delegate from whatever class you're using it in. However, I don't know what would be the delegate to assign for a UIButton. I've tried changing the class to UIResponder to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIControl API

`func addTarget(_ target: AnyObject?,
          action action: Selector,
forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)`

But what are you trying to do? Normally you would add a button in interface builder and a reference (IBOutlet) to that button from some controller class like UIViewController.

**edit**

Ah, now I see the problem. Don't use Selector in swift.
This should work.

```
helpButton.addTarget(self, action: "showOptions", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I'm trying to add the function `showOptions` which is inside class `Support` to `helpButton` using `addTarget`. I could just as easily put `showOptions` inside of the viewController in which I'm adding the button and set the target in `addTarget` to the viewController I'm passing in but thats kind of messy if you do it enough.

Comment: and setting all the button attributes is not messy? Why do that in code when IB can do it for you. Also ShowOptions is what NSViewController is for: to deal with user events and shuffle (modified) data between the backend and frontend. Don't fight the cocoa system too much. It has a good design and a way of doing things. It can make life so much easier. Also, you can add custom objects to your viewController in IB (blue box in the side panel). Hook up your viewController to that object and then hook up your buttons to that custom controller (like your would with nextResponder or FileOwner).

Comment: I'm familiar with IB I just don't prefer it.

Comment: Oh boy, then you are just making life hard for yourself for no (apparent) good reason. What are your objections against IB?

Comment: I use storyboards to lay out the flow of an application but the elements I do not. If I need to grid out 20 views I can do it in a simple for-loop as opposed to dragging outlets and then naming them. IB is suited for quick and simple applications but for anything complex it becomes a hassle pretty quickly. So once you're used to doing it for every element it doesn't make a lot of sense to change over for a few small things. I actually wrote a blog post about this: https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/draftselftaughtswift-adding-elements-without-using-storyboard-110a1e6b1#.s2cxtge8j

Comment: Yeah, that is a good reason. In that case, setting the action and target of a button shouldn't be that difficult a task? Did the method I mentioned work?

Comment: `addTarget` was in my original post. No that does not work.