# Swift: Unrecognized selector sent to class, buttons target in NSObject class

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried the various solutions but doesn't quite work. I am creating a headerView in my FormViewController (I'm using Eureka) and I separated my views into a separate `HeaderViews: NSObject` to observe the MVC principle.

I attempted to add a buttonTarget but it throws the error `unrecognized selector sent to class`. My code is as follows:

```
class ProfileSettingsViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        form +++
            
            Section(){ section in
                section.header = {
                    var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.callback({
                        let view = HeaderViews.setUpHeaderForProfileView(user: self.user)
                        return view
                    }))
                    header.height = { 200 }
                    return header
                }()
            }
        }
```

And in my HeaderViews:

```
class HeaderViews: NSObject {
    
    static func setUpHeaderForProfileView(user: User) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.width, height: 100))
        let changeAvatarButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (screen.width / 2) - 50, y: avatarImageView.frame.maxY + 10, width: 100, height: 20))
        changeAvatarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getAvatar(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(changeAvatarButton)
        return view
    }

    func getAvatar(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Change Avatar tapped")
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if I have made any mistake, as I have tried various methods of the selectors in this post: [Unrecognized selector sent to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428993/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class)

I suspect it might something to do with the subclass NSObject. What can I try next?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35540652/1025063)?

Comment: @Imad hm no, did not see that post. Seems like I have to refactor my code accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: try changing action: #selector(getAvatar(_:)) to action: #selector(getAvatar())

Comment: try changing action: #selector(getAvatar(_:)) to action: #selector(getAvatar

Comment: @MohammadSadiq tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
If you could not get instance of `HeaderViews`. then just change `getAvatar` to static funciton.

```
static func getAvatar(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Change Avatar tapped")
}
```

**Origin**
You should not use `self` as target in static function.
Because this `self` means `HeaderViews`.
Passing instance to function as target.

Ex:

```
static func setUpHeaderForProfileView(user: User, in instance: HeaderViews) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.width, height: 100))
    let changeAvatarButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (screen.width / 2) - 50, y: avatarImageView.frame.maxY + 10, width: 100, height: 20))
    changeAvatarButton.addTarget(instance, action: #selector(getAvatar(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(changeAvatarButton)
    return view
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What would feed into the HeaderViews argument in the FormViewController?

Comment: If you cant understand. Just try to change `getAvatar` to static.

Comment: Very happy to help you ：）

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the UIButton Parameter, define **func getAvatar()** with no parameters or func getAvatar(_ sender: AnyObject?)

The function call would change to this.
**changeAvatarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getAvatar), for: .touchUpInside)**

Also I am curious why not define **HeaderViews** as a subclass of **UIView**?

That might actually be the problem here.

Comment: I have tried various selector methods, with or without arguments, but doesn't seem to work. I also tried subclassing to UIViews too, doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Have u tried changeAvatarButton.addTarget(view, action: #selector(getAvatar), for: .touchUpInside) ?